# How to assign VBA to a keyboard shortcut in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, vba, macros

Okay this sounds silly. I am trying to assign a Macro to a keyboard shortcut in Microsoft Word.

Let's say I want to assign macro `LangUS` to a keyboard shortcut

[image]

I want to assign the macro to shortcut CTRL + SHIFT + L. While Microsoft Excel prompts me to assign a keyboard shortcut before recording, this is not the case in Microsoft Word.

In addition, online resources encourage me to use `Option` button in Macro. However, there is no Option button. The available button is `Organizer` which displays another thing

[image]
[image]

I'm not familiar with VBA coding as well so I can't directly write the codes in the VBA editor

Any ideas on how to assign a shortcut to a Macro in Word? TIA.

Answer (score 5):

### You can assign a macro to a keyboard shortcut in Word rather simply.

Here is my article on the MS website about [assigning keyboard shortcuts](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-msoversion_other/assigning-keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft-word/a346f277-e0eb-4d17-b53b-233584c611bb?tm=1595883735330).

Here are just the steps required to add the keyboard shortcut to a macro in Word for Windows 2010 or later:

> 1. File > Options
> 2. Customize the Ribbon
> 3. Customize Keyboard (Button)
> 4. Choose the storage location for your customization (Either the
>    normal template or the current document/template)
> 5. Choose what category it is you want to use the shortcut on (i.e.
>    macros, styles)
> 6. Pick the specific macro, command, style, building block to which
>    you will assign the shortcut
> 7. Click in the box for the new shortcut and press your shortcut
>    combination. Look to see if already assigned.
> 8. Click on the Assign button.
>
> [image: screenshot from article]
>
> Repeat steps 1-8 as needed. Then Close the Customize Keyboard
> dialog and OK your way out of the Customize the Ribbon dialog.
>
> If prompted, save changes to the template.

Note, [the article](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-msoversion_other/assigning-keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft-word/a346f277-e0eb-4d17-b53b-233584c611bb?tm=1595883735330) also contains steps for other versions of Word as well as other kinds of things to which a keyboard shortcut can be assigned.

Answer (score -1):

Use a third-party popular and free utility, autohotkey. Make sure to use the extensive help they have available.

Comment: Thanks for the insights! Does Word not provide feature to assign Macros to keyboard shortcuts unlike Excel?

Comment: IMO, it is easier in Word than in Excel. See my answer.